# Joining z-values (from point file) to map generated by Kriging in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, kriging

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.0.

I am making a fertilizer application map that changes the rates, based on the location of the field. **The overall goal of the operation is to create a grid of squares, each with a grid containing a result of the Kriging interpolation.**

I have a point file with nitrogen nutrient levels, the result of a soil-sampling operation:

[image]

The attribute table (with a row with for each point) that comes with it looks like this:

[image]

I want to know the specific level of nitrogen (NO3) in the field, so I used Kriging to interpolate it:

[image]

Now I have to convert from a floating-point raster to an interval raster. To do this, I first converted the floating-point raster (produced by Kriging) to an integer raster using the "Int" tool. Then, I used the "Raster to Polygon" tool to create my grid map. The grid produced is below:

[image]

I'm trying to get each of the grids to represent one of the Kriged nitrogen levels, but when I do a joins-and-relates action, I get a table with a bunch of unknown values.

I need the grids to reflect the values of the Kriging map that was generated earlier. How can I do that? Am I missing a joins-and-relates somewhere?

Comment: Do you have spatial analyst? (if you're performing Kriging then you should have either spatial analyst or 3d analyst) if so Sample https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/sample.htm may be what you're after. Otherwise resample your raster to your grid size (mean) https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/resample-function.htm and perform a raster to point could be an alternative.

Comment: @MichaelStimson yes, I have both of them. I will try this, thank you!